# How to retrieve variable from CMS page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cms-pages, variables, magento2.2

### In Magento 1.9.x, we can do it like below

In CMS page, add content:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="..." my_vars="123,456" template="path-to/test.phtml"}}
```

Create `path-to/test.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getData('my_vars'); ?>
```

---

My question is: how to achieve it in **Magento 2**?

Hope somebody could say more detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use in Magento 2 like this

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml" my_vars="123,456"}}
```

Now you can get the data by calling:

```
$myVar = $block->getData('my_vars');
```

**OR**

```
$myVar = $block->getMyVars();
```

**Note:** You should use **$block** instead of **$this**

Comment: Thanks firstly. `Vendor_Module` corresponding to which path? Suppose I have theme 'frontend/Vendor/lumachild', where should I put the template file? It seems can't find the file.

Comment: If you have theme then you should use `Magento_Theme`. Full code like this: `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml" my_vars="123,456"}}`

Comment: I put the test.phtml in the theme root folder, but it can't be shown. What's the correct path should I put?

Comment: Put test.phtml at this path `app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/test.phtml`

Comment: Still not work, use the Magento CE 2.1.7, you could try it.
`{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml" my_vars="123,456"}}`
test.phtml at this path `app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/templates‌​/test.phtml`
Maybe lost some steps?

Comment: If I create new module and block, it worked, but  can't work in Magento_Theme, didn't find the reason. I found some blogs about using Magento_Theme to create template, but didn't work too. Could you give some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Here you pass value from cms block/page

```
 {{block ... category_id="value here" ... template="test/test.phtml"}}
```

In test.phtml:

```
$this->getData('category_id');
```

you can also get it By

```
$block->getCategoryId();
```