# HTML tag in widget not show as HTML element when insert to the CMS page

Tags: magento2, widget

I have created a widget text box that contains just an HTML tag.

```
<h1>Some heading</h1>
```

and then insert this widget to a CMS page with url: "cms_page_link".
When I hit the CMS page URL, for example: 
`http://example.com/cms_page_link/`
the page show that widget content just as string with quoted:

```
"<h1>Some heading</h1>"
```

not the HTML element as I expected:

## Some heading

Have anyway to get HTML tag as normal?

Comment: Can you post your code lines of widget here?

Comment: Ah none code, I'm just create widget via admin

Answer (score 1):

### Solution - "CMS Static Block" widget

1. Go to `Content -> Blocks`, create a new block, write `<h1>Some heading</h1>` in it and save.
2. Go to the CMS page you want to edit, insert the widget **CMS Static Block**, in the widget select the block you just created, then save the page and it will work.

[image: html widget]

### Solution - Template

Write codes like this `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml" my_vars="123,456"}}` in your page. Create the template file in you module, you could use variable in it, it is a flexible way. You could get some info from [How to retrieve variable from CMS page in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190584/how-to-retrieve-variable-from-cms-page-in-magento-2)

Comment: Oh, I known this approach, but I am wanna to use a widget, not CMS blocks

Comment: @viethung But it is indeed a widget type `CMS Static Block`,  it doesn't have obvious difference with `created a widget text box that contains just an HTML tag`. If you doesn't like this way, you could use **template**, not widget. I will add it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in the template `htmlspecialchars_decode($variable);`